# What is the proper way to construct a Python package/module referencing a .PYD?

Tags: python, windows, dll, swig

I am a rookie to the Python world, and now I find myself trying to learn how to properly create a Python package or module. I also have several requirements that must be met.

I have a core native DLL (we'll name it **MyCore.dll**) compiled from C++. This DLL must be deployed to a particular install location, as it's a core component of a product (we'll say **ProgramFiles\MyProduct**).

I have used SWIG to generate Python bindings for **MyCore.dll**. It has generated 2 files: **_MyCoreBindings.pyd** (essentially a DLL that references **MyCore.dll**) and **MyCoreBindings.py** (which loads **_MyCoreBindings.pyd** and provides a Python API to it).

Finally, I have a Python script (**MyProduct.py**) containing only an import, as my product must be imported in Python under the name *MyProduct.SDK* :

```
import MyCoreBindings as SDK
```

Thus, I want a user's Python script to be able to access it like so:

```
import MyProduct.SDK
```

File summary in order of dependency:

- **ProgramFiles\MyProduct\MyCore.dll**
- **_MyCoreBindings.pyd**
- **MyCoreBindings.py**
- **MyProduct.py** (I'm not sure I need this)

I've also read that the format of a Python package involves some directory structure mimicking the import path, and the possible inclusion of **setup.py** and **__init__.py**, but all materials I've read have not made it clear what must go in each of these files, and in what cases they are required. I am definitely not clear where this directory structure may be placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Python to be able to import your module, then you have a couple of choices:

- install the module to Python's `site-packages` folder.
- modify the paths that Python searches for modules/packages to import. You can do that via a *.pth file or by modifying the path using Python's `sys` module (i.e. sys.path.append(/some/path) )

You use `setup.py` for installing your package and/or creating eggs/wheels etc. See the following for helpful hints:

- https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html
- https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html

You can create a package by using `_init__.py` inside a folder alongside your modules:

```
- MyProduct
  - __init__.py
  - MyCoreBindings.py
  - _MyCoreBindings.pyd
```

The `_init__.py` file can be empty. This basically allows you to import the folder as `MyProduct`:

```
import MyProduct

MyProduct.MyCoreBindings
```

or

```
from MyProduct import MyCoreBindings as SDK
```

You won't need a `MyProduct.py` if you go with the `__init__.py` in the root folder. I hope that all made sense.

Comment: In your scheme, **_MyCoreBindings.pyd** is not adjacent to **MyCore.dll**, which it links to. Is there any way in **__init__.py** to ensure that **ProgramFiles\MyProduct\MyCore.dll** ends up in the dll search path when **_MyCoreBindings.pyd** is loaded?

Comment: You could certainly put the dll and everything else in the same folder. You would just need to make sure you update Python's search path, which is what the `sys.path.append` and the `*.pth` files are for